# Excel VBA Find Function Taking a Long Time

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have written a short function to search a set of strings with another set of strings in an Excel workbook. The function is as follows:

```
    Function CheckForString(Target As Range, List As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Output As String
    Output = "No Match"


    For Each Item In List

        If Output = "No Match" Then
            If Not Target.Find(Item.Value) Is Nothing Then Output = Item.Value
        End If

    Next

    CheckForString = Output

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    End Function
```

The problem is that I am using this function to search in about 400,000 strings for any of about 2,000 other strings. I've set it up and let it run for hours and it's not finishing calculating.

So there are 400,000 instances of =CheckForString() in the worksheet and they are cycling through a ~2,000 cell range. All I need to do is see if any of the strings in the 2,000 appear in each of the 400,000 cells. E.g.:

String: "    APPLES-BANANAS    123459    "

Strings to find:

APPLES-BANANAS

APPLES BANANAS

So if it "hits" on the first one, I don't care if it find any more. I just need to know that at least one of the strings to find is in there.

Thanks for any thoughts on how to speed this up!

Best,

Grrollins

EDIT: To the questions so far in the comments (and thank you for taking the time!)

The data I am searching are strings containing serial numbers (alpha numeric) but that don't have a consistent format and include extra junk, whitespace, other characters, etc.

I have a pristine set of serial numbers that I am trying to compare to the large data dump. The goal is to identify which of these strings in the large set contain a string that could be a serial number from my list, so I can look further at those records and create a report using them.

I hope that makes it a little more clear! Thanks again!

I'll try the Exit For also. If anything, maybe it'll shave a few hours off!

Comment: Can you describe the business need and required output in more detail?

Comment: You could stick 'Exit For' into your If statement to avoid it continuing looping once you come across a first match. It won't solve all your problems but it's a start.

Comment: Sounds like it would be better to re-organize your data(structure) before you try to find the needle in your haystack

Comment: Thank you; I added some additional info to the post!

Comment: With the addition of "Exit For" I'm actually getting a Calculating % that is moving, which is promising! It still looks like it's on a path to take all day.

Comment: If calculation is slowing you down and your procedure is not reliant on calculations being completed during each step of your loop, try entering application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual in your procedure BEFORE the loop is called, then you can set it back with application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic once you have finished looping. This will avoid performing unnecessary calculations during each iteration.

Comment: string manipulation functions could be tried, but depending on huge volume and randomness of data, give more detail like : data format example and your required output on what degree the match should be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subroutine `MarkStrings` will highlight in green all the strings from `Target` that contain as substring something from the`List` range.

The main ideas:

- work "on stack memory" with simple data structure;
- avoid repetitive conversions of the same item;
- use `Strings` functions rather then `WorksheetFunction` functions (also, way *way* faster).

You can re-purpose the `Sub` to do what you want, of course. Please note that **is not the same idea** as your `Function`. While your function is called for a lot of cells, this subroutine should be called once, for all the `Target` range—see the `Test()` subroutine.

```
    Public Sub Test()

            Call MarkStrings(Sheet1.Range("C3:DG303"), Sheet1.Range("A1:B2"))

    End Sub


    Public Sub MarkStrings( _
       ByVal Target As Range, _
       ByVal List As Range _
    )

            Dim raw           As Variant
            Dim str_target()  As String
            Dim str_list()    As String

            Dim m As Long, m_min As Long, m_max As Long
            Dim n As Long, n_min As Long, n_max As Long
            Dim p As Long, p_min As Long, p_max As Long
            Dim q As Long, q_min As Long, q_max As Long

            ' 0. Check ranges '
            If (Target Is Nothing) Or (List Is Nothing) Then
                    Exit Sub
            End If

            Let Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            ' 1. Load the entire Target in memory, and make it string '
            Let raw = Target.Value

            Let m_min = LBound(raw, 1)
            Let m_max = UBound(raw, 1)
            Let n_min = LBound(raw, 2)
            Let n_max = UBound(raw, 2)

            ReDim str_target( _
               m_min To m_max, _
               n_min To n_max _
            )
            For m = m_min To m_max
            For n = n_min To n_max
                    Let str_target(m, n) = CStr(raw(m, n))
            Next n
            Next m

            Let raw = Empty

            ' 2. Load the entire List in memory, and make it string '
            Let raw = List.Value

            Let p_min = LBound(raw, 1)
            Let p_max = UBound(raw, 1)
            Let q_min = LBound(raw, 2)
            Let q_max = UBound(raw, 2)

            ReDim str_list( _
               p_min To p_max, _
               q_min To q_max _
            )
            For p = p_min To p_max
            For q = q_min To q_max
                    Let str_list(p, q) = CStr(raw(p, q))
            Next q
            Next p

            Let raw = Empty


            ' 3. Loop trough Target and check elements in List. If found, '
            '    make cell background green and go to next target.        '
            For m = m_min To m_max
            For n = n_min To n_max
                    For p = p_min To p_max
                    For q = q_min To q_max
                            If Strings.InStr( _
                               Start:=1, _
                               String1:=str_target(m, n), _
                               String2:=str_list(p, q), _
                               Compare:=vbTextCompare _
                            ) > 0 Then
                                    Let Target.Cells(m, n).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                    GoTo NEXT_TARGET
                            End If
                    Next q
                    Next p
    NEXT_TARGET:
            Next n
            Next m

            Let Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Searching 4 strings in a range of approx. 300×100 took a second on my machine. For your case, it should take (400000×2000)/(4×30000) ~= 6700 seconds ~= 2 hours.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about re-implementing with arrays instead of creating a worksheet function. I created something similar to the above and it seems to be moving much faster. I've actually put a little scripting in the macro to kick up a message box every 15 minutes so I can see how far through the range it has progressed.

Comment: It didn't even make it to the 15 minute mark. The process completed in about 4 minutes.

Comment: @grrollins Wow, this is one of the rare cases when I was pessimistic about the performance of the code; I should do this more often. :-)

Comment: +1: Very nice optimization! I would probably use collections or dictionaries, but this should do the trick just fine.

Comment: @Nanashi Thanks for the compliment. :-) I thought about `VBA.Collection` too, but the thing is, you need to find substrings, not entire strings, so you cannot use keys from `List` to identify elements in a `Target` content collection.

Answer (score 0):

Appologies but i do not understand that why do we not use range.find method. The scenario is that target range may have 4,00,000 rows and almost 2000 rows need to be searched. Using find loop will be for only 2000 times. and will get result in few seconds only and the code will be much faster

```
Function myfind(targetrng As Range, sourcerng As Range)

On Error Resume Next

Dim c As Range
Dim cell As Range


    Set c = targetrng.Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)

    If c Is Nothing Then
            myfind = "No Match"
        Else
            myfind = "Match Found"
    End If


End Function
```

Comment: You can use this function in the worksheet as "=myfind(targetrng,sourcerng)" and you will get result against each 2000 rows as "Match Found or not Found"